# Differentiate unique and primary key constraints exceptions in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, constraints

I'm trying to insert some data into the table `usertb`(`user_id`, `name`, `email`, `mobile_number`) where `user_id` is the primary key and `mobile_number` unique key.

When I'm inserting a record with existing mobile_number, I am encountering an exception:

### Exception:

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

This will also come primary key constraint. How we can differentiate it unique key constraint exception or primary key constraint exception?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only chance you have is to insert the row without the `mobile_number`. And then, quickly after that try to update the row with the `mobile_number`

Comment: thank you Suero, sorry for the inconvenience , i am missing  the information in my question , as new user enrolling in that time,checking  the mobile number is already user table or not , so i want to insert mobile number immediately. if any alternative option using find unique key constraint exception.

Comment: @user3373821 Can you post the entire stacktrace that is thrown in both cases?